# XmL script stacking

Tags: xml, t-sql

I did a search but with no success on how to search the correct way in regards to what I'm looking for. I'm building a XML T-sql script in SSMS 2014. My mission is to make a stack of images in my XML file.

Part(1): As you can see they are nicely stacked. Problem is if I make a sub query in my main query the alias doubles up my tags - Part (2).

From-Clause:

```
(from propertycombined as [Property] 
join (select  psa.guiPropertySummaryID,a.szFirstName,a.szLastName,o.szOfficeName,o.szPhoneNumber,o.szTollFreePhone,
                o.szFaxNumber,o.szAddress_1,o.szaddress_2,o.szCity,o.szState,o.szCounty,o.szZipCode,o.szCountry,a.szEmailAddress,a.szAgentWebPageAddress
                from PropertySummaryAgents psa join Associates a  on psa.guiassociateID = a.guiAssociateID
                    join AssociateOffice ao on a.guiAssociateID = ao.guiAssociateID
                    join office o on ao.guiOfficeID = o.guiOfficeID
                where  psa.bytTeamOrder = 1 
                    and a.bytStatus = 1) as [ContactData] on Property.guipropertycombinedID = ContactData.guiPropertySummaryID
    join ( select guipropertySummaryID, REPLace([image].szphotofilename,'_!.','_S.')[photo]
            from photos [image]
                    join propertycombined pc on pc.guipropertyCombinedID = [image].guipropertySummaryID
                where pc.szcompanyListingStatus in ('Active','Pending')
and pc.bitMktg_WebApproval = 1
group by[image].guipropertySummaryID,[image].szphotofilename ) as [Images]  on [Images].guipropertySummaryID = [Property] .guipropertycombinedID
where Property.szcompanyListingStatus in ('Active','Pending')
and Property.bitMktg_WebApproval = 1
and Property.guibrokerid in  (select guibrokerID from Broker where bitActiveBroker = 1)
For XML Auto ,Root ('Properties'), ELEMENTS)
```

Part(1)

```
<Images>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_001_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_002_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_003_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_004_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_005_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_006_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_007_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_008_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_009_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_010_P.jpg</image>
  <image>Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_011_P.jpg</image>
</Images>
```

Part(2)

```
      <Images>
        <Image>Localhost/10206/1215%2BDevries%2BRd%2BOak%2BHarbor%2BWA%2BUSA%2B450500_001_S.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Images>
        <Image>Localhost/10206/1215%2BDevries%2BRd%2BOak%2BHarbor%2BWA%2BUSA%2B450500_001_P.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Images>
        <Image>Localhost/10206/1215%2BDevries%2BRd%2BOak%2BHarbor%2BWA%2BUSA%2B450500_002_S.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Images>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Is this still open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best (best in performance, readability and intuitiveness) to use `FOR XML PATH`:

Look at this and adapt it to your needs:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ImagePath VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_001_P.jpg')
,('Localhost/6127/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_002_P.jpg')
,('Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_003_P.jpg')
 ,('Localhost/6127/151%2BSaint%2BAndrews%2BDrive%2BSpartanburg%2BSC%2BUSA%2B397806_004_P.jpg');

--this is what you do not want->Images is each row's surrounding tag
SELECT ImagePath AS [Image]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('Images') 

--this is the way you like it-> Images is just the main root tag
SELECT ImagePath AS [Image]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Images')
```